# scipy results linear interpolation results inconsistent

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I need to perform linear interpolation on a data containing `'n'` independent variables and a dependent variable. I am currently using `scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator` for performing the interpolation. However, when I change the range of the data set by multiplying all values (of a variable) with a constant the result after interpolation changes completely.

Let me illustrate this with a specific example:

```
 X = [[0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00], [0.00000000e+00, 8.00000000e+00], [0.00000000e+00, 1.60000000e+01], [0.00000000e+00, 3.20000000e+01], 
      [0.00000000e+00, 6.40000000e+01], [0.00000000e+00, 1.28000000e+02], [1.00000000e-06, 1.00000000e+00], [1.00000000e-06, 8.00000000e+00], 
      [1.00000000e-06, 1.60000000e+01], [1.00000000e-06, 3.20000000e+01], [1.00000000e-06, 6.40000000e+01], [1.00000000e-06, 1.28000000e+02], 
      [1.00000000e-06, 2.56000000e+02], [1.00000000e-06, 5.12000000e+02], [1.00000000e-05, 1.00000000e+00], [1.00000000e-05, 8.00000000e+00], 
      [1.00000000e-05, 1.60000000e+01], [1.00000000e-05, 3.20000000e+01], [1.00000000e-05, 6.40000000e+01], [1.00000000e-05, 1.28000000e+02], 
      [1.00000000e-05, 2.56000000e+02], [1.00000000e-05, 5.12000000e+02], [1.00000000e-04, 1.00000000e+00], [1.00000000e-04, 8.00000000e+00], 
      [1.00000000e-04, 1.60000000e+01], [1.00000000e-04, 3.20000000e+01], [1.00000000e-04, 6.40000000e+01], [1.00000000e-04, 1.28000000e+02], 
      [1.00000000e-04, 2.56000000e+02], [1.00000000e-04, 5.12000000e+02], [1.00000000e-03, 1.00000000e+00], [1.00000000e-03, 8.00000000e+00], 
      [1.00000000e-03, 1.60000000e+01], [1.00000000e-03, 3.20000000e+01], [1.00000000e-03, 6.40000000e+01], [1.00000000e-03, 1.28000000e+02], 
      [1.00000000e-02, 1.00000000e+00], [1.00000000e-02, 8.00000000e+00], [1.00000000e-02, 1.60000000e+01], [1.00000000e-02, 3.20000000e+01], 
      [1.00000000e-02, 6.40000000e+01], [1.00000000e-02, 1.28000000e+02]]
 y = [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 6.99000000e-17, 5.60000000e-16, 1.12011400e-15, 2.24034300e-15, 
      4.48080000e-15, 7.56193140e-14, 2.17896343e-13, 5.02450401e-13, 6.99000000e-16, 5.60000000e-15, 1.12011430e-14, 2.24034290e-14, 4.48080000e-14, 8.96171430e-14, 
      1.79235429e-13, 3.58472001e-13, 6.99000000e-15, 5.60000000e-14, 1.12011429e-13, 2.24034286e-13, 4.48080000e-13, 8.96171429e-13, 1.79235429e-12, 3.58472000e-12, 
      6.99000000e-14, 5.60000000e-13, 1.10000000e-12, 2.20000000e-12, 4.50000000e-12, 9.00000000e-12, 6.99000000e-13, 5.60000000e-12, 1.12000000e-11, 2.24000000e-11, 
      4.48000000e-11, 8.95000000e-11]
```

When I perform interpolation for values `[7.10000000e-05, 18]` I get the result `7.95281146e-14`. If I were to multiply the first column by `10^3` and the results column by `10^12` then the result I get is completely different. I get `0.09352` which is equivalent to `9.352e-14`.

- Can someone throw some light on why scipy is giving different results in these cases?
- which of these results is right? (I tried using excel however I soon realized that scipy uses a different technique).
- How should I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by multiplying the 'first column' and the results column ?

Comment: The data of the first column of X is in the range of 1e-6 to 1e-2 (if you exclude the zeros). This range was changed to 1e-3 to 1e+1 by multiplying elements of that column by 10^3. Similarly all elements of y are multiplied by 10^+12.

Comment: `LinearNDInterpolator` uses Delaunay triangulation to triangulate the data point positions (`X` here), then linearly interpolates inside each triangle using the data at each of the three points per triangle. The Delaunay triangulation is sensitive to the data point positions. You will not get the same triangulation if you scale one of the position coordinates differently than the other. Consequently, the position that you are trying to interpolate will be getting `y` data from a different set of three points.

Comment: @Kern Thanks for the answer. I expected this to be the reason and had not thought machine precision. Is there a way to address the problem. Which of these is closer to correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of machine precision. Bluntly speaking, your y - values are of and even beyond the magnitude of the rounding errors, that is about `1.1e-16` for double precision floats.

Check this reference for a better explanation [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is responsible for such a large change in results. Is that right? If so, the result 9.352e-14 is more accurate? In the case of other data values I am not observing such a large change in values. I am observing a problem only in the case of N-Dimensional interpolation. Is this because it involves more operations than linear interpolation?

Comment: Your error is about `0.1e-14` what is close to machine precision. I suggest you try to implement this with quadruple float precision. It's hard to say, which result is better, since the behavior of round-off errors hard to track. It would require an analysis of the interpolation function.

Comment: oh yeah. true... did you check this error for other data? what is the absolute value there?

Comment: Most of the other errors where I use linear interpolation is of the order 1e-15. (0.1e-14).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I have in the past read the article you mentioned, but during the course of implementation forgot about it. I tend to assume that the exponent will be handled by the machine separately. I forgot that during the course of floating point addition/subtraction the number is denormalized. Given the fact that x-axis is much larger, I suppose such loss in precision is expected.

Answer (score 3):

As Robert Kern states above, the answer is that both answers are correct. They however answer different questions.

When interpolating scattered data at, say, point `(x, y)`, the algorithm must know the answer to the question: "which of the data points are closest to `(x, y)`. Now, the obvious way to do this, and which Delaunay triangulation used in the algorithm is based on, is to use the Euclidean distance:

```
distance = sqrt((x[i] - x)**2 + (y[i] - y)**2)
```

Now, if you scale the x-coordinates by 1e3, the answer to the "which point is closest" question obviously can change as the y-coordinates become much less important.

The correct choice is to use a scaling for which the Euclidean distance makes sense. If you are doing physics, the x- and y- coordinates should have the same units or be both dimensionless.

Comment: I understand why the answer is different based on the equation you have given. However, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "x- and y- coordinates should have the same units or be both dimensionless". If I am trying to interpolate the time taken in a distance (x) vs time (y) then x and y are bound to have different units. The units of x and y are very different in this case.

Comment: Speaking as a physicist: your problem probably has some "typical velocity" that you can multiply the time coordinates with, to produce sensible results. On the other hand, if your data is dense, this choice has only little effect: note that even in the present case where your data is sparse the difference was only 20% between a large change of scaling. The point here is that you are using prior knowledge about the data to interpolate it between data points.